# SQL Divide values by a total sum, groupwise

Tags: sql-server, aggregation, percentage

I have a table like:

```
user_id  operation   amount  
1        purchase    10  
1        sale        40
2        purchase    100
2        sale        20
2        conversion  15
3        sale        70
4        conversion  40
```

given by the SQL query:

```
SELECT  
  user_id,
  operation,
  COUNT(item_num) AS amount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY user_id, operation
```

I want to calculate, for each user, the percentage of the total amount for each operation and it would be nice to place them in the columns(actually dividing numbers):

```
user_id  purchase   sale      conversion
1        10  /50    40 /50    0  /50
2        100 /135   20 /135   15 /135
3        0   /70    70 /70    0  /70
4        0   /40    0  /40    40 /40
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the intuition given in the responses, I was able to find the solution that suits me best

```
WITH result
AS
(
    SELECT
        [user_id],
        [operation],
        CAST(COUNT([item_num]) AS float) AS amount,
        SUM(COUNT([item_num])) over(partition by [user_id])  AS total_amount

    FROM Mytable
    GROUP BY user_id, operation
)

SELECT
    [user_id],
    ROUND(ISNULL([purchase], 0) / total_amount, 2)   AS purchase,
    ROUND(ISNULL([sale], 0) / total_amount, 2)       AS sale,
    ROUND(ISNULL([conversion], 0) / total_amount, 2) AS conversion
FROM result

PIVOT
(
    MAX(amount)
    FOR operation IN ([purchase], [sale], [conversion])
) x

ORDER BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you. You will need to use a CTE with the columns and a sum() over() calculating the total sum per user_id.
With that information, all you need to do is pivot the result and give the formatting desired. If you need the division and not just showing what its dividing, remove the formating and concatenation.

```
WITH Sum_Over AS

(

    select  user_id,operation, amount,sum(amount) over(partition by user_id) AS Total_Sum
    from #test
)

SELECT user_id

,CAST(ISNULL([purchase],0) AS VARCHAR(5))+'/'+CAST(Total_Sum  AS VARCHAR(5)) AS [purchase]

,CAST(ISNULL([sale],0) AS VARCHAR(5))+'/'+CAST(Total_Sum  AS VARCHAR(5)) AS [sale]

,CAST(ISNULL([conversion],0) AS VARCHAR(5))+'/'+CAST(Total_Sum  AS VARCHAR(5)) AS [conversion]

FROM Sum_Over

PIVOT (
max(amount)
FOR operation IN ([purchase],[sale],[conversion])
)x

ORDER BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Jader is cleaner.  This one uses Group By:

```
With result As
(
SELECT  
  user_id,
  Sum(amount) as tot,
    Case When operation = 'purchase' Then 
    convert(nvarchar(5),sum(amount)) + '/' +  convert(nVarChar(50),(Select sum(amount) From MyTable t Where t.user_id = x.user_id))
    End As [purchase],

    Case When operation = 'sale' Then 
    convert(nvarchar(5),sum(amount)) + '/' +  convert(nVarChar(50),(Select sum(amount) From MyTable t Where t.user_id = x.user_id))
    End As [sale],

    Case When operation = 'conversion' Then 
    convert(nvarchar(5),sum(amount)) + '/' +  convert(nVarChar(50),(Select sum(amount) From MyTable t Where t.user_id = x.user_id))
    End As [conversion]


FROM MyTable x
GROUP BY user_id, operation
)
Select user_id,
isnull(Max(purchase),'0/' + convert(nVarChar(50),sum(tot))) As purchase,
isnull(Max(sale),'0/' + convert(nVarChar(50),sum(tot))) As sale,
isnull(Max(conversion),'0/' + convert(nVarChar(50),sum(tot))) As conversion
From result
Group By user_id
```